# Is there a way to modify the default coroutine context created by Spring?

Tags: spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

Using Spring WebFlux and Kotlin Coroutines, methods in controllers are usually (if they invoke other suspending functions) marked with the `suspend` modifier. That means that Spring implicitly creates coroutines to call them, and it does that with some coroutine context . Is there a way to have control over that coroutine context? In particular, I'd like to add MDCContext to every coroutine context that Spring creates.

Comment: For WebMvc it can be done [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437892/configure-default-kotlin-coroutine-context-in-spring-mvc) I do not know if it's transferable.